# Bibtex with "ociamthesis" class and Bibliography style "ormsv080"

Tags: bibtex

I am writing my thesis using `ociamthesis` class and bibliography style `ormsv080`. I have a large number of citations and when I am compiling the master file which looks as following, I am not getting any citations. For all the citations, I am getting following error:

```
Citation `Gerchak1994' on page 3 undefined
```

If I run one of the chapters as a stand alone file, it works. The `.bib` file is in the same folder as the master file and chapter files.

Please suggest a solution to the problem.

Here is the master file:

```
%\documentclass[12pt]{ociamthesis}   % default square logo 
\documentclass[12pt,squarelogo]{ociamthesis} % use old belt crest logo
%\documentclass[12pt,shieldcrest]{ociamthesis} % use older shield crest logo

%load any additional packages
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{pdflscape} 
\usepackage{graphviz}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{bigstrut}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
%\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{subfigure}

\bibpunct[, ]{(}{)}{,}{a}{}{,}%
 \def\bibfont{\small}%
 \def\bibsep{\smallskipamount}%
 \def\bibhang{24pt}%
 \def\newblock{\ }%
 \def\BIBand{and}%


\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
%\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{verbatim}   % useful for program listings
\usepackage{color}      % use if color is used in text
\usepackage{subfigure}  % use for side-by-side figures
\usepackage{hyperref}   % use for hypertext links, including those to external documents and URLs
\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing

\setlength{\parskip}{10pt}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\newtheorem{Thm}{PROPOSITION}


\newtheorem{theos}{Theorem}

\newtheorem{hypos}{HYPOTHESIS}

%input macros (i.e. write your own macros file called mymacros.tex 
%and uncomment the next line)
%\include{mymacros}

\title{}     %your thesis title,
         %note \\[1ex] is a line break in the title

\author{}             %your name
\college{}  %your college

%\renewcommand{\submittedtext}{change the default text here if needed}
\degree{}     %the degree
\degreedate{}         %the degree date

%end the preamble and start the document
\begin{document}

%this baselineskip gives sufficient line spacing for an examiner to easily
%markup the thesis with comments
\baselineskip=18pt plus1pt

%set the number of sectioning levels that get number and appear in the contents
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}


\maketitle                  % create a title page from the preamble info
\include{dedication}        % include a dedication.tex file
\include{acknowlegements}   % include an acknowledgements.tex file
%\include{abstract}          % include the abstract

\begin{romanpages}          % start roman page numbering
\tableofcontents            % generate and include a table of contents
\listoffigures              % generate and include a list of figures
\listoftables
\end{romanpages}            % end roman page numbering

%now include the files of latex for each of the chapters etc

\include{Chapter1}
\include{Chapter2}
\include{Chapter3}
\include{Chapter4}
\include{Chapter5}


%now enable appendix numbering format and include any appendices
\appendix
\include{appendix1}
\include{appendix2}
\include{appendix3}

%next line adds the Bibliography to the contents page
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography}
%uncomment next line to change bibliography name to references
%\renewcommand{\bibname}{References}

\bibliographystyle{ormsv080}  %use the plain bibliography style
\bibliography{REF_SHELFSPACE}        %use a bibtex bibliography file refs.bib

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Answer (score 1):

Do you run bibtex and latex multiple times? I would recommend the following:

```
set name=Abschlussarbeit
set latex_cmd=-synctex=-1 -max-print-line=120 -interaction=nonstopmode %name%.tex

pdflatex %latex_cmd%
bibtex %name%
makeindex %name%.idx -t %name%.ilg -o %name%.ind
makeindex -s %name%.ist -t %name%.alg -o %name%.acr %name%.acn
makeindex -s %name%.ist -t %name%.glg -o %name%.gls %name%.glo
makeindex -s %name%.ist -t %name%.slg -o %name%.syi %name%.syg
pdflatex %latex_cmd%
```

Comment: Do you really need to run makeindex four times? Does this really solve the problem?

Comment: There's no sign in the question that `\printindex` is used, nor `glossaries`; thus running `makeindex` is not needed.

Comment: This is not necessary for this problem. But if you use glossaries package.

Comment: Only running `bibtex` seems necessary; you should make clear that this is Windows specific and that the code is the contents of a `.bat` file.